# defparameter vs defun for passing functions around

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So I can do this:

`(defparameter *some-function* ... ; returns lambda later`

or this:

`(defun some-function ...`

With either, I can use `funcall`:

`(funcall 'some-function ...`
or
`(funcall *some-function* ...`

With the `defun` version I can also do this:

`(some-function ...`

I cannot do that with the `defparameter` function.

`defparameter` provides easier technique for re-assigning `some-function` to a different function (or anything else, including non-function data) later.

But other than these two points, what are other considerations of using one over another?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, fundamentally, you _may_ also want to consider `flet` and/or `labels`, which I find a nice description of [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/the-special-operators.html#manipulating-the-lexical-environment).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an odd one to answer as we are somewhat comparing apples with oranges.

*For those new to lisp who are looking at this, defparameter is for defining a dynamic variable whereas defun is for defining a function.*

If you are worried about being able to programmatically reassign a function without using defun check out the following:

```
CL-USER> (defun jam () (print 'some-jam))
JAM

CL-USER> (jam)
SOME-JAM 

CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'jam) (lambda () (print 'some-ham)))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA ()) {1004C033DB}>

CL-USER> (jam)
SOME-HAM
```

So defparameter doesn’t have an advantage when it comes to reassigning a function. Also if you want to redefine the function you could look into [the compile command](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp.htm).

Comment: You can also use `(setf (fdefinition 'jam) ...)` here, and [`fdefinition`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm) will work on _all_ function names (including `(setf ...)` functions, not just symbols.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Brilliant, I didn’t know about that. Cheers (also good point about let)

Comment: There's still an advantage with `defparameter` that `let` will bind a new value and _restore_ the old value automatically for you, without you having to store it explicitly.  E.g., compare the two snippets in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/8sLLnEPJ).

Comment: For those looking at *that paste*, consider using `unwind-protect` to restore the fdefinition.

Comment: Note that "A call within a file to a named function that is defined in the same file refers to that function, unless that function has been declared notinline. The consequences are unspecified if functions are redefined individually at run time or multiply defined in the same file." http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_bbc.htm

Comment: Or just use `defun` again: `(defun jam () (print 'some-ham))`. ;-) `defun` is not like `defvar` in not updating.

Comment: This question shows another important distinction between defparameter and defun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919918/