# Why does this defun closure not behave the same as the defparameter closure?

Tags: lisp, closures, common-lisp

Consider these two:

```
(defparameter *lfn*
  (let ((count 0))
    #'(lambda ()
    (incf count))))

(defun testclosure ()
    (let ((count 0))
      #'(lambda ()
      (incf count))))
```

Why do they behave differently:

```
CL-USER> (funcall (testclosure))
1
CL-USER> (funcall (testclosure))
1
CL-USER> (funcall *lfn*)
1
CL-USER> (funcall *lfn*)
2
```

`count` is closed over in the `defparameter` version but not in the `defun` version. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sylwester's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920096/1281433) explains this very well, but in a case an example with more explicit side effects makes this any clearer, consider:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *foo* (progn (print 'hello) 0))
HELLO 
*FOO*
CL-USER> *foo*
0
CL-USER> *foo*
0
```

In defining `*foo*`, the `(progn (print 'hello) 0)` is evaluated once, so `hello` is printed, and the value is `0`, which becomes the value of `*foo*`. Evaluating `*foo*` later just means looking up `*foo*`'s value (`0`)`, not reëvaluating the form that produced its original value.  In contrast, consider calling a function whose body is`(progn (print 'hello) 0)`:

```
CL-USER> (defun foo () (progn (print 'hello) 0))
FOO
CL-USER> (foo)
HELLO 
0
CL-USER> (foo)
HELLO 
0
CL-USER> (foo)
HELLO 
0
```

Each time `foo` is called, `(progn (print 'hello) 0)` is evaluated, so `hello` is printed and `0` is returned.  After seeing this example, your code should be a bit clearer.

```
(defparameter *lfn*
  (let ((count 0))
    #'(lambda ()
    (incf count))))
```

`(let ...)` is evaluated once, and the closure that that evaluation produces its the value of `*lfn*`.  On the other hand, in

```
(defun testclosure ()
    (let ((count 0))
      #'(lambda ()
      (incf count))))
```

`(let ...)` is evaluated every time that `testclosure` is called, a new closure is returned each time.

Answer (score 8):

When you are making `*lfn*` you are creating a function within one closure.. Calling it will increase the closed over count and evaluate to it.

`testclosure` does the same as what you did with `*lfm*` for every time it gets called. Thus:

```
(defparameter *lfn2* (testclosure))
(funcall *lfn2*) ; ==> 1
(funcall *lfn2*) ; ==> 2
(funcall *lfn2*) ; ==> 3
```

Will make exactly the same as `*lfn*` such that consecutive calls to it will increase the value returned. However

```
(funcall (testclosure)) ; ==> 1 (and the closure can be recycled)
(funcall (testclosure)) ; ==> 1 (and the closure can be recycled)
```

Here you are doing `funcall` on a newly created closure, that you don't store for consecutive calls, so it will return 1. Then you are doing `funcall` again on a completely new closure that you also don't store and it's first call also evaluates to 1.

So the answer is, count is closed over in both, but in you example you were creating a new closure and using it only once, several times.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `*lfn*` is a closure.

The function `testclosure` returns a new closure each time you call it.